# Ajax sends null data into controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a liferay portlet and use Spring MVC. I want to use Ajax to send a basic object into controller. The problem is that controller receives only null object.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="graphui.GraphUIConstants" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<portlet:resourceURL var="sendPersonURL" id="<%= GraphUIConstants.SEND_PERSON %>" />

<script>

    function URL_SEND_PERSON_KEY() { return '${sendPersonURL}'; }

    function sendPerson(){

        var company = new Object();
        company.id = 1;
        company.name = "coName";

        var person = new Object();
        person.name = "James";
        person.age = 40;
        person.email = "james@james.com";
        person.company = company;

        var personInJSON = JSON.stringify(person);

        AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){
            A.io.request(URL_SEND_PERSON_KEY(), {
                   method: 'post',
                   data: personInJSON,
                   on: {
                        success: function() {
                         alert(this.get('responseData'));
                        }
                   }
            });
        });

    }

</script>

<div>

    <ul>
        <li>${name};</li>
        <li>${age};</li>
        <li>${email};</li>
    </ul>  

    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendPerson()"> Send </button>

</div>
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, int age, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**Company.java**

```
public class Company {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**GraphUIConstants.java**

```
public class GraphUIConstants {

    public static final String SEND_PERSON = "sendPerson";

}
```

**GraphUI-portlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="graphui" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
   </bean>

   <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/> 

   <!-- Spring MVC Message Source -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>content.graph</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">
<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>GraphUI</portlet-name>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <ajaxable>true</ajaxable>
        <header-portlet-javascript>/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    </portlet>

    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>

</liferay-portlet-app>
```

**GraphViewController.java**

```
package graphui;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ActionMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;

/**
 *
 * Controller for VIEW mode of portlet.
 */
@Controller("graphViewController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class GraphViewController{

    private static final String MODEL_KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String MODEL_KEY_AGE = "age";
    private static final String MODEL_KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private Person repository = new Person("pete", 33, "pete@pete.com");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GraphViewController.class);

    @ActionMapping(GraphUIConstants.SUBMIT_FORM)
    public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception {

            logger.info("action phase executed");

            if (request.getParameter("name") != null)
                repository.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            if (request.getParameter("age") != null)
                repository.setAge(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")));
            if (request.getParameter("email") != null)
                repository.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));

    }

    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {

      logger.info("render phase executed");  

      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_NAME, gson.toJson(repository.getName()));
      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_AGE, gson.toJson(repository.getAge()));
      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_EMAIL, gson.toJson(repository.getEmail()));
      return new ModelAndView("index", model);
    }

     @ResourceMapping(GraphUIConstants.SEND_PERSON)
public void savePerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person jsonString, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {

   logger.info("savePerson method was executed");

   String name = jsonString.getName();
   String age = Integer.toString(jsonString.getAge());
   String email = jsonString.getEmail();

   String name2 = request.getParameter(MODEL_KEY_NAME);
   String age2 = request.getParameter(MODEL_KEY_AGE);
   String email2 = request.getParameter(MODEL_KEY_EMAIL);

   String name3 = ParamUtil.getString(request, MODEL_KEY_NAME);
   String age3 = ParamUtil.getString(request, MODEL_KEY_AGE);
   String email3 = ParamUtil.getString(request, MODEL_KEY_EMAIL);

   logger.info("Person name is " + name);
   logger.info("Person age is " + age);
   logger.info("Person email is " + email);

   logger.info("Person name is " + name2);
   logger.info("Person age is " + age2);
   logger.info("Person email is " + email2);

   logger.info("Person name is " + name3);
   logger.info("Person age is " + age3);
   logger.info("Person email is " + email3);

}

}
```

When I send Person object by Ajax, I get this message in log:

```
12:52:18,726 INFO  [GraphViewController:65] savePerson method was executed
12:52:18,728 INFO  [GraphViewController:79] Person name is null
12:52:18,728 INFO  [GraphViewController:80] Person age is 0
12:52:18,729 INFO  [GraphViewController:81] Person email is null
12:52:18,729 INFO  [GraphViewController:83] Person name is null
12:52:18,729 INFO  [GraphViewController:84] Person age is null
12:52:18,729 INFO  [GraphViewController:85] Person email is null
12:52:18,730 INFO  [GraphViewController:87] Person name is 
12:52:18,731 INFO  [GraphViewController:88] Person age is 
12:52:18,731 INFO  [GraphViewController:89] Person email is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){
                A.io.request(URL_SEND_PERSON_KEY(), {
                       method: 'post',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: {"<portlet:namespace />person" : JSON.stringify(person)},
                       contentType: "application/json",
                       on: {
                            success: function() {
                             alert(this.get('responseData'));
                            }
                       }
                });
        });
```